# Selecting the Multiple Rows randomly in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row

Can I select the multiple rows randomly in JTable?

I tried with

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(index 0, index 2);
```

It will select three rows 0,1 and 2, but I need to skip the selection of index 1.

How can I accomplish this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to set a discontinous selection with a single method call, you need at least two:

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
table.addRowSelectionInterval(2, 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

set Jtable properties- 
selectionModel- Multiple Interval Selection

The first row selection should be done with setRowSelectionInterval(i,j)
The subsequent row selections (in the same JTable) should be done with addRowSelectionInterval(i,j)

Use

```
ListSelectionModel selectionModel = 
  jTable1.getSelectionModel();
selectionModel.setSelectionInterval(1, 1);//for first row selection
selectionModel.addSelectionInterval(3, 3);
selectionModel.addSelectionInterval(5, 5);
```

this

and link:
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=11760

Comment: -1 nothing new compared to the earlier answer ... plus: the default mode already _is_ multipleInterval plus: don't dig down into the api of a field if there's direct api to do the same